# Difference between chmod +x vs sudoing an executable

Tags: shell, command-line, permissions, sudo, root

A user can execute an executable by : sudoing which allows a user to run an executable as the owner or by setting the execute bit, chmod u+x (or should it be chmod **a**+x ?).

So what is the real difference between the two given that they have the same effect, that is, to allow someone else than the owner to run the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you meant to ask specifically about `chmod o+x`, to enable `other` (i.e. someone who is neither the `user` nor a member of the specified `group`) users to execute the file. `chmod a+x` is a superset of `chmod o+x` since it turns on the execute permission for all 3 (`user`, `group`, and `other`).

The difference then is the context in which the program will run. With `sudo` the program runs in the context of the specified user; without `sudo` the program runs in the context of the current user. For some scripts this might not matter at all, but if anything involving user permissions is involved, it matters. Maybe it would help to explain this with a hypothetical malicious script that will delete all files in the user's home directory:

If the user `alice` runs `sudo -u bob deleteHomeFiles.sh` then the files in bob's home directory would all be deleted. On the other hand if `alice` ran `deleteHomeFiles.sh` directly, the files in alice's home directory would be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A rather large difference is the fact that if you run a program directly, it runs with the rights of your user id, but with `sudo`, you're using somebody else's user id and their rights:

Consider your usual system where `/bin/ls` is executable by anyone, and `/root` is readable only by the `root` user itself:

```
$ /bin/ls /root/test
/bin/ls: cannot access '/root/test': Permission denied
```

but

```
$ sudo /bin/ls /root/test
hello.txt
```

or `id` versus `sudo id`.

Note that the user id matters not only in access to files, but also e.g. in sending signals to processes, and of course `root` can do lots and lots of other administrative stuff that regular users cannot.

Of course `sudo` by default runs the program as root, but the difference is in principle the same even if you use `sudo -u johnnie` instead.

Comment: but what if '/root/test' had chmod a+x ? wouldn't it again produce 'hello.txt'?

Comment: @microwth, if both `/root` and `/root/test` are accessible to everyone, and `/root/test` is readable by everyone, then yes, you could get the listing even without `sudo`. But that's beside the point: there are files and directories that are not world-readable, and using someone else's UID allows other things too (like killing their processes). Of course I could have used `cat /etc/shadow` or `pkill sshd` as examples.